# How to convert text format JSON array into JSON object array in NodeJS / JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

I have a REST API created using Node.JS and ExpressJS.
I need to receive a JSON array from FrontEnd into my REST API.

```
api.post('/save_pg13_app_list', function (req, res) {
        var app_list = {
            list_object: req.body.list_object
        };
        console.log(app_list.list_object);
        res.json({ type: "success", code: 200, data: app_list.list_object });
    });
```

This `list_object` is the JSON array I'm getting from the Front End.

This is the POST endpoint for the task.

> http://localhost:7000/api/admin_control_manage/save_pg13_app_list

And this is the data object I'm receiving :

```
{
 list_object :  "[{name:\"chanaka\",\"code\":10},{name:\"shashini\",code:19}]" 
}
```

When I'm taking this `list_object` in my REST API , it's a String Object. 
Now I need to parse this to JSON.
So I used following code to convert this to JSON.

```
var json_array = JSON.parse(app_list.list_object);
```

But I'm getting this error :

> POST /api/admin_control_manage/save_pg13_app_list 500 0.936 ms - 1212
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 2
>       at Object.parse (native)
>       at /home/chanaka/WebstormProjects/PostureAPI/app/routes/admin_control.js:210:26
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/chanaka/WebstormProjects/PostureAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (/home/chanaka/WebstormProjects/PostureAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (/home/chanaka/WebstormProjects/PostureAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/chanaka/WebstormProjects/PostureAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at /home/chanaka/WebstormProjects/PostureAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
>       at Function.process_params (/home/chanaka/WebstormProjects/PostureAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
>       at next (/home/chanaka/WebstormProjects/PostureAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
>       at Function.handle (/home/chanaka/WebstormProjects/PostureAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:3)

All I need to do is, convert `[{name:"chanaka",code:10},{name:"shashini",code:19}]` kind of string array into JSON. What is the way to do this ?

Comment: log to the console the value of `app_list.list_object` just before you do the `parse`. It is best to output it as `console.log(JSON.stringify(app_list.list_object))`. It looks like it is undefined.

Comment: @Chanaka De Silva your json is not valid.keys should have quotation marks.return correct json from your api

Comment: @trincot error says `Unexpected token n in JSON at position 2`.so it's not undefined right?

Comment: If indeed the JSON string is like `"[{name: ......]"` then you are right. The OP did not present it like that (as a quoted string), so it is confusing.

Comment: @trincot Can you please suggest me a solution ?

Comment: See my first comment. Can you tell us the output? (exactly with all backslashes, quotes, ...)

Comment: @trincot I sent this object via POSTMAN : [{name:"chanaka","code":10},{name:"shashini",code:19}] ... And this is the JSON.stringify output : "[{name:\"chanaka\",\"code\":10},{name:\"shashini\",code:19}]"

Comment: Yep, then @MadhawaPriyashantha has it right. You are not sending valid JSON. That's the cause of your problems. `name` must be between double quotes. This also means you are building that JSON through string manipulation (constructing it "yourself"). This is bad practice and leads to this kind of situations. Use a proper JSON builder. I edit his output into your question...

Comment: Also, I note a confusion of terms in your question. You talk about parsing the string "to JSON". But JSON is text! What you get from parsing it, would be (if valid) a JavaScript object (don't call *that* JSON).

Comment: @trincot Sorry if i'm disturbing you. Is there any better way to take a JSON object array into NodeJS POST endpoint ? And i think this JSON is valid. [{
  "name": "chanaka",
  "age": "22"
} , {
  "name": "chanaka",
  "age": "22"
}]

Comment: @trincot I fixed that and now it's working well.. Thank you guys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try stringifying the object in the callback function;

```
res.json({ 
    type: "success", 
    code: 200, 
    data: JSON.stringify(app_list.list_object) 
});
```

JSON stringify will format it correctly so it’s gets properly parsed